# What's the best way of importing bootstrap into react project

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I found a couple of ways to import bootstrap into my project. I'm rather unsure if there is a best practice.

I installed `bootstrap` and `react-bootstrap` using npm.

**Option 1: Import every component seperately**

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button variant="outline-secondary" id="button-addon1">
        Button
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

vs. **Option 2: Import everything**

```
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <bs.Button variant="outline-secondary" id="button-addon1">
        Button
      </bs.Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My guess:

Option 1 is leaner as it only imports the component I use. But is it the best way to use it? Especially when Prototyping out a quick idea it can get filled with imports quickly or can be a pain to import everything hand by hand.

Any advice is very welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with Option 2. Bootstrap's components names are very generic and could be confused with other components.

Comment: IMO it's not a valid point, because even with default imports you can use aliases, i.e.: "import MyAliasForBsButton from 'react-boostrap/Button";

Answer (score 0):

Importing the specific component from the library rather than importing everything improves the performance while fetching and rendering.

However,

**You can also import multiple components from a single import statement**

```
import { Form, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
```

**You can also use the default react-bootstrap syntax to import**

It imports dynamically without naming the specific components

```
import * as ReactBootstrap from "react-bootstrap";



return (
    <ReactBootstrap.Button bsStyle="success" bsSize="small">
      Button
     </ReactBootstrap.Button>
    );
```

So, In terms of performance, multiple components imports or individual component imports are way better than the others.

Comment: With tree shaking, it's not true.

Answer (score -1):

You can just include the link to the CSS and JS bundle in the **public/index.html**

You can find the CSS link here -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/
[image: 1]

Copy the CSS code and paste it into the **head tag**

You can find the JS bundle here -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

[image: 2]

Copy the JS Bundle code and paste it right on top of the end of the body tag. Like this

```
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"> //This is the JS Bundle
  </script>
</body>
```

You can just use the bootstrap class names on className of the component which will be easier to refer on the bootstrap docs.

```
<div className="d-flex mx-2 bg-dark"></div> //Usage of bootstrap classes
```

Comment: he is talking about named imports vs default imports, not about how to include bootstap in the project: "I installed bootstrap and react-bootstrap using npm."

Comment: Ofc!. But this would be an easier way as we have very good docs by bootstrap for class names.

Comment: What would be an easier way? He wrote that he has installed bootstrap and react-bootstrap. Thus he can use bootstrap classes without any problems. His question was about importing react-bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

There are **default imports** (option 1) and **named imports** (option 2). Generally, the main difference is that with option 1 you import only the component, not the whole library: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/getting-started/introduction/#importing-components

> You should import individual components like: react-bootstrap/Button
> rather than the entire library. Doing so pulls in only the specific
> components that you use, which can significantly reduce the amount of
> code you end up sending to the client.
>
> ```
> import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
>
> // or less ideally
> import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
> ```

I said generally, because you can set up your bundle tool for **tree shaking**. With tree shaking you remove everything, that is not used in your code, resulting in the same bundle size, as you would import only certain components directly via default imports.

I use option 2, because I like to clip all the imports from the same library. It's also easier for eyes to parse the imports IMO.

Comment: Tree shaking is not entirely reliable. This article provides insight on why that's the case: https://advancedweb.hu/2017/02/07/treeshaking/

Comment: So you post an 5,5yo article? It's like an eternity in frontend...The author talks about Webpack2 while the current version right now is 5 already. https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ Did you do the test and compared the bundle size when using named import vs default import? For me it's the same. Especially react-bootstrap is NOT delivered with bundled CSS.

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/9ba8c7c341c249b342099685768d7001d5e10b76/package.json#L31